# SwiftUI Bug: Popover in Toolbar slows down Mac app (memory issue)

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I've found this SwiftUI bug when adding a Popover to Toolbar on Mac app drastically slows down the overall performance. As soon as I perform any action app starts using more and more memory.

By the way, for this to start happening you don't even have to show Popover itself – he fact that its in your code is already enough. As soon as you exclude Popover code things instantly back to normal.

Here is my code: a simple draggable view, dragging around of which makes app slow after 3~5 seconds already and memory.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var popUpPresented = false
    @State private var position: CGPoint = .zero
    @State private var offset: CGPoint = .zero
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .overlay(Text("Drag me around").foregroundColor(.black))
                .position(position)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 150)
                .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0, coordinateSpace: .local)
                    .onChanged { value in
                        position.x = offset.x + value.translation.width
                        position.y = offset.y + value.translation.height
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        offset = position
                    })
        }
        .frame(width: 600, height: 600)
        
        .toolbar {
            Button (action: {popUpPresented.toggle()}) {Text("Popup")}
            .popover(isPresented: $popUpPresented, arrowEdge: .top) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Here's how memory usage foes from 20Mb to over a 40Mb just in couple of seconds:
[memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuOBt.png)

Try deleting these two lines of code inside of toolbar and you'll see memory not going wild anymore.

```
Button (action: {popUpPresented.toggle()}) {Text("Popover")}
.popover(isPresented: $popUpPresented, arrowEdge: .top) {Text("Any text")}
```

Tested in Xcode 12 and 13 show same result.
Dear community, please help in solving this mystery and finding workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Your code (with minor change of adding a NavigationView) 
works without any problems for me 
on macos 12.0(21A5522h), xcode 13.beta5 (not release), 
target ios 15 and macCatalyst 12. Maybe it is different on older systems.
Tested with and without the `popover`, and the `toolbar` and the `Button`.

Comment: @workingdog I have added NavigationView, but it doesn't help.Please notice that it is NOT iOS, this happens with MAC app.

Comment: yeah, I tested in a macOS only app (with and without the NavigationView), the memory is higher, but nothing too drastic. The response is very good.

Comment: @workingdog Here im experiencing a massive memory leak. And it looks like im not the only one: github.com/matt-curtis/mac-swiftui-toolbar-memory-leak-demo (これかなりひどいリークやで)

Comment: Don't get me wrong  (あなたを信じています), I'm only reporting what I have tested.                           
I looked at the link you show, and I do not get any of the problems mentioned.

I do not get `print("You should see this message printed twice.")` of the first example.
I do not get `print("You should see this message printed many times.")` of the second example.

Like I said maybe with older systems it is different, but I do not get any of the
problems mentioned.

Comment: Gotcha. So its gotta be an OS thing probably. Any chance you could test it on your Big Sur OS, please? I would appreciate a lot @workingdog

Comment: sorry but I only have macOS Monterey beta 7, Xcode 13-beta5. Had to delete Xcode 13 release, because it was just too bad, and only caters for macos 11.3.  It would be good if someone could test this on Big Sur.